# delete a value in multidimensional array

Tags: go, multidimensional-array

I have an error in the function `DeleteCharactersID`, it removes the entire multidimensional array but I need to delete a single element or value using the id that I gave it.

This my domain.go

```
type CharactersBB []struct {
    CharID                   int        `json:"char_id"`
    Name                     string        `json:"name"`
    Birthday                 string        `json:"birthday"`
    Occupation               []string      `json:"occupation"`
    Img                      string        `json:"img"`
    Status                   string        `json:"status"`
    Nickname                 string        `json:"nickname"`
    Appearance               []int         `json:"appearance"`
    Portrayed                string        `json:"portrayed"`
    Category                 string        `json:"category"`
    BetterCallSaulAppearance []interface{} `json:"better_call_saul_appearance"`
}
```

This my services.go

```
var characters []domain.CharactersBB

func DeleteCharactersID(i string) ([]domain.CharactersBB, error) {
    id, err := validateID(i)
    if err != nil {
        return []domain.CharactersBB{}, ErrorInvalidID
    }

    c, err := searchCharacter(id)
    if err != nil {
        return []domain.CharactersBB{}, err
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(characters); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(characters[i]); j++ {
            if characters[i][j].CharID == c[j].CharID {
                characters[j] = append(characters[i][:j], characters[i][j+1:]...)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", c)
    return characters, nil
}

func validateID(id string) (int, error) {
    num, err := strconv.Atoi(id)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }
    return num, nil
}


func searchCharacter(id int) (domain.CharactersBB, error) {
    var c domain.CharactersBB
    for a := range characters {
        if c[a].CharID == id {
            return c, nil
        }
    }
    return domain.CharactersBB{}, ErrorCharactersNotFound
}

func init() {
    var c domain.CharactersBB

    url := baseurl + "characters"
    resp, _ := http.Get(url)
    Data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(Data), &c)
    characters = append(characters, c)
    //s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(characters, "", "\t")
    //fmt.Println(string(s))
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", characters)
}

func GetCharacters() ([]domain.CharactersBB, error) {
    return characters, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
characters[j] = append(characters[i][:j], characters[i][j+1:]...)
```

Your inner array counter is `j`, your outer array counter is `i`, so it seems like this should be:

```
characters[i] = append(characters[i][:j], characters[i][j+1:]...)
//        ^^^ fix here
```

Comment: yes but when a http delete in postman with id then i have a this error : [Recovery] panic recovered:
DELETE /deletecharacters/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8086
578dd126d1daae56534bccb10399c294: 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 541
Content-Type: application/json
runtime error: index out of range
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/panic.go:502 (0x42ac18)
        gopanic: reflectcall(nil, unsafe.Pointer(d.fn), deferArgs(d), uint32(d.siz), uint32(d.        goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP

Comment: The error in postman is what your browser gets. Troubleshoot the stacktrace you get from the application itself.

Comment: I think `== c[j].CharID` is causing an index out of bounds error. `c` isn't necessarily the same length as `characters[i]`. Try using the comparison `characters[i][j].CharID == id` and see if that (in addition ton Adrian's answer) gets the result you want.